# Problems with build angular part in asp.net

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, wwwroot

I have a project on Angular, that does not contain problems or errors. However when i `build --prod` project in Asp.net, I'm having problems.

I build a project in:

```
...
 "apps": [

    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../wwwroot",
...
```

and my Asp.net most likely does not see this folder. Or what? 
The server starts, however it is empty and nothing is loaded from the folder wwwroot. If I manually try to navigate the routes, I get 404.

What is the problem?